# assume role keys are getting expired after every one hour how to write a logic so that keys can be refreshed after every one hour while

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a application with AWS which is in A Account to get records from Dynamo DB which is in another account B.

I assume a role which is in account A to get a temp credentials to get records from Dyanamo DB. but it will be expired in a short time. After the credentials are expired, the Application will not be stopped, just sleep a while and wakeup again.

How can I avoid the credentials expired or how can i refresh the token after every 1 hour is there any way

Comment: AssumeRole returns temporary credentials. It doesn't provide an option for persistent credentials. For that you'd need IAM User credentials (which is a bad practice for apps). If your app runs in AWS (e.g. on EC2, ECS, or Lambda) then you can launch it with an IAM role and let the AWS SDK that you use take care of refreshing the credentials. Otherwise, you should be able to detect the expiration of the temporary credentials because expiration is one of the values returned by AssumeRole.

Comment: `how can i refresh the token after every 1` - by assuming role again

Comment: You haven't provided any information about which programming language you use, how you're currently getting or planning to get credentials, or if your app is even running on an AWS compute service. If you're using an AWS SDK, see if the credentials provider that you are using has a refresh method. You can then run a timer and refresh when needed. The SDK will otherwise auto refresh, but you typically can't control the schedule afaik.